# Vue JS error Parsing error: Unexpected token - Error is absolutely useless

Tags: javascript, vue.js, eslint

I am trying to learn frontend framework Vue. Following [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/ZqgiuPt5QZo?t=4187). This is my first time with JS and I only know basic javascript concepts. Searching for these issues, it seems like it has something to do with ESlint? I tried all configurations in the answers but nothing works.

My error:

```
  88:20  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token

  49 |       if (this.newEntryContent && this.selectedEntryType !== 'draft') {
  50 |         this.user.entries.unshift( items: {
> 51 |             id: this.user.entries.length + 1,
     |                     ^
  52 |             content: this.newEntryContent
  53 |         })
  54 |       }

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)
```

My template:

```
    <form class="form" @submit.prevent="createNewEntry">
      <label for="new-entry">New entry</label>
      <textarea name="new-entry" rows="4" v-model="newEntryContent"></textarea>
      <div class="entry-type">
        <label for="entry-type">Type: </label>
        <select id="entry-type" v-model="selectedEntryType">
          <option :value="option.value" v-for="(option, index) in entryTypes" :key="index">
            {{ option.name }}
          </option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <button>Post</button>
    </form>
```

Here is my `<script>`.

```
<script>
import EntryItem from "@/components/EntryItem";

export default {
  name: 'UserProfile',
  components: { EntryItem },
  data() {
    return {
      newEntryContent: '',
      selectedEntryType: 'instant',
      entryTypes: [
        {value: 'draft', name: 'Draft'},
        {value: 'instant', name: 'Instant'}
      ],
      followers: 0,
      user: {
        id: 1,
        username: 'john',
        firstName: 'John',
        lastName: 'Doe',
        isAdmin: true,
        entries: [
          {id: 1, content: "My submission"},
          {id: 2, content: "My awesome entry to another contest!"}
        ]
      },
      log: ""
    }
  },
  watch: {
    followers(newFollowercount, oldFollowercount) {
      if (oldFollowercount < newFollowercount) {
        this.log = oldFollowercount;
      }
    }
  },
  computed: {
    fullName() {
      return this.user.firstName + ' ' +this.user.lastName;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    followUser(){
      this.followers += 1
    },
    toggleFavourite(id) {
      console.log("You faved " + id);
    },
    createNewEntry() {
      if (this.newEntryContent && this.selectedEntryType !== 'draft') {
        this.user.entries.unshift( items: {
            id: this.user.entries.length + 1,
            content: this.newEntryContent
        })
      }
    }

  },
  mounted() {
    this.followUser();
  }
}
</script>
```

The error is absolutely useless and it is not saying much about anything. There are no errors in the console too. How should I debug this and fix?

Comment: remove `items:` it's an api/type hint from their IDE

Comment: This worked thanks. I did have a confusion there about the syntax but hearing how weird js is, I thought it was actually how things are done. I am really missing python now. Worked. thanks. thanks. thanks. :)